# return #ERROR Formula Parse error when trying to access data from a 2nd Sheet on the same file

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty new to using Excel/Google Sheets as I've never needed it in previous jobs. This query isn't for a work project but for a personal record to keep information I want to record clear and concise, Kind of like keeping books for a business I am trying to record various income's and outgoing's in the form of "points" (Maybe Google Sheets isn't the best "free" tool to use) that will show how many "points" someone has accrued, How they earned them, and What if any they have spent them on, It will also be recording some cash transaction as well.

I have 2 sheets currently and I am trying to add all the data for a single person from 1 Sheet into the "Points Total" column on the other sheet taking into account what they have earned and what they have spent.

I'm not sure how else to explain it really, Here is my current butchered (seriously) formulae:

***=sum(C2:F2), - 'Point Purchases'!C2***

[Link to the Google Sheet in question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M_eXgXe_2S4LHefQrDpFfYGyTrQBAiGM0hEv3bk-oCU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mot that far off. Just remove the comma.

```
=sum(C2:F2) - 'Point Purchases'!C2
```

Comment: damn those comma's, It's generally something simple and daft like that haha. Thanks for the help work's like a charm.